# User with Minimum Access Profile/Permission Set Cannot See Any Buttons on Object Pages

Tags: lightning, custom-button, permissions, profile, button

We recently created a new profile cloned from the Salesforce Minimum Access profile and added the rest of the necessary permissions for the users via Permission Sets/Groups.

We noticed the users with this Profile/Permission Set combination cannot see any buttons (standard or custom) on any object pages other than the Chatter follow button. The buttons are added in the Lightning/Mobile section of the page layouts and other users can see the buttons.

[image]

This does seem to be lightning specific as when we switch to classic the user can see the standard/custom buttons.

[image]

Are there any special permissions needed to see these buttons? We've reviewed a bunch of the System/Object/Page permissions and haven't found what's missing as to why the users cannot see any buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you still need it but for me it turned out that my profile was missing **Publisher Layout assignment**.
Minimum Access Profile on default has no Publisher Layout assignment.
It is strange that the lack of this assignment also resulted in errors on some standard **Paths** like Lead Status path.